# =IF syntax error in google docs

Tags: if-statement, syntax, google-docs

i made a simple =IF syntax for my inventory

=IF((D2<(3*E2)),"ORDER","ADEQUATE")

it works fine in my excel, but in google docs it only work on my first row, at the second row and so on it will give wrong result

http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/7710/g5wf.jpg

I tried to make new =IF syntax in different column, it will give right result at first. when i test it with changing the value in D2 or E2, the result won't change even when it should.

I tried 'fill'ing next row with the working first row, still wont work

tried replacing the comma with semi-column, not working

tried changing the formula in other column to: IF ( D2 < E2 , 1 , 2), still only work at the first time, after that changing the value will give wrong result

tried download the gdocs to excel, open it in my computer, works just fine. save it, re upload to gdocs, only first row giving right result

Has anybody had this problem, or does anybody think they know what's going on?

thanks!

Comment: Can you add the tag, "Google-Docs?"  This isn't an excel question. / Incidentally, the formula is valid and should work. When using in Excel and Google Docs, if you drag the bottom right corner down, the program fills the formula down and uses relative cell references. I have tested it in Google Docs and Excel and it works. I would suggest trying a different browser.

Comment: thanx for the comment. i tried opening it on android, firefox, and also IE. only the first row shows right answer

Answer (score 15):

I've noticed that for myself , because of region settings I assume, I've to replace the  "," in the formulas with ";"

Comment: What the actual fuck. Ran into the exact same issue and thought I'm going crazy as the `=IF(TRUE,4,5)` example from the docs threw an error. Why is this not mentioned prominently? (edit: it's actually shown correctly in the help tooltip but easy to overlook)

Comment: This fixed my IF statement. Had to use ; to separate elements. Thanks.